# Centering a View on top of another view in JavaFx

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm trying to center a view on top of another view essentially in an anchor pane.

Here is my code:

```
<AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
    <children>
        <ListView fx:id="list" prefHeight="750.0" prefWidth="300.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
        <ProgressIndicator fx:id="bar" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**This is what it looks like:**

[image]

**This is my goal:**

[image]

**EDIT:**

Updated code to include a stackpane

```
<AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
          <children>
            <StackPane prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0">
              <children>
                <ListView fx:id="list" />
                <ProgressIndicator fx:id="bar" />
              </children>
            </StackPane>
          </children>
        </AnchorPane>
```

Comment: so, what's the problem?

Comment: @SergeyGrinev As you can see in my first photo the progress view shows in the upper left, but I want it to stay centered in it's parent.

Comment: Why not simply use a `StackPane`? Or why not set the alignment?

Comment: @fabian when I try to center the alignment via anchors the progress view size stretches and when I try to set alignment via `BorderPane.alignment="CENTER"` it doesn't seem to do have any affect.

Comment: I think fabian suggested that you try a `StackPane` as your root pane. Meaning, replace your `AnchorPane` with a `StackPane`.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson so my code isn't my whole layout but just a small snippet. I need the anchorpane and the listview, but my idea now is the before the first item loads in the listview, I want to show an indeterminant progress bar, so that's why I want to center it on top of the list view. Let me know if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: The answer is still the same. If you put the `ListView` and the `ProgressBar` inside of a `StackPane`, they should automatically center.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson aha. I didn't know. Excuse my ignorance on the topic. As you can see in my history I do mostly Android, and was thinking there was a way to centerInParent=true type of thing. I will try this now and come back with my results.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson so after I put my listview into the stackpane the listview doesn't seem to fill the entire stackpane. Any ideas? I've edited my question with the updated snippet.

Comment: I suggest you try [Gluon SceneBuilder](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/).

Comment: @SedrickJefferson I'm using that actually. What option am I looking for to adjust the layout correctly in this gui scene builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

The key to filling the `StackPane` is to set the `ListView`'s maxHeight and maxWidth to Double.MAX_VALUE.

```
<children>
  <StackPane AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
     <children>
        <ListView maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" />
        <ProgressIndicator maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" progress="0.44">
           <StackPane.margin>
              <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
           </StackPane.margin>
        </ProgressIndicator>
     </children>
  </StackPane>
```

> The prefHeight and prefWidth for the `StackPane` and `ListView` may not reflect what you have in your original post. You can change these values to suit your needs. I also set Constraints on the `StackPane` so that it fills its Parent `AnchorPane`.

SceneBuilder Images:

[image: StackPane Layout Properties]
[image: ListView Layout Properties]
[image: ProgressIndicator Layout Properties]

You may need to set the preferred side of `ProgressIndicator`

Comment: Great. My only issue with this is that the height and width aren't fixed. The progress indicator is huge. Any way to keep it at it's default size? Sorry if there's no such thing, but I come from an Android background and I can set a Progress bar height and width to "wrap content" and it just takes a default height and width. Anything like that or do I have to set something specifically?

Comment: Set preferred size and set max size to preferred size.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know if there was a default value.